# Retrieve cell value based on date Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a time sheet for my work schedule. In column A I have the start dates of each week. In the second column I have how many hours I work that day. I am payed on the 22nd of each month. I want to have a running total of how much I have earned in a month before payday. That is to say on the 21st I know how much money I will be paid the next day from my spreadsheet.

I want to SUM the values of column B but only for the weeks which lie between the 22nd of 'April' lets say and 'May'.

Therefore based on the value of the start date of the week, I need to obtain the information adjacent to the weeks, for a set of weeks and sum it to find the number of hours I've worked this paying month. I want this to happen automatically, so it will change automatically.

I have attached a screenshot which might make this clearer, I have added a couple of other names as additional variables.

Thank you in advance,
Maksim Richards

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: in column G where it says total pay this month so far by your name why can't you just sum column B and multiply it by your pay rate?  it will only sum cells that you have entered hours worked.  any cells that are zero won't cause you a problem.  did you need it to do anything else besides that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the amounts that you'll get in next month's pay haven't been filled in yet (which is the question you're asking because you want to find out on 21st May how much you will be getting) then you just need to sum the amounts for the weeks starting 22/4/16 onwards in G9:-

```
=SUMIF($A$4:$A$11,">="&DATE(YEAR($F$2),MONTH($F$2)-1,$G$2),B$4:B$11)
```

where today's date is in F2 and payday in G2.

Then the pay so far is:-

```
=G9*24*$H$2
```

where the hourly rate is in H2 (result may appear formatted as date: if so, change format to general).

If you wanted to check back after some of next month's hours had been put in the spreadsheet and see if what you've actually been paid is the same as your calculated pay you would need a SUMIFS:-

```
=SUMIFS(B$4:B$11,$A$4:$A$11,">="&DATE(YEAR($F$2),MONTH($F$2)-1,$G$2),$A$4:$A$11,"<"&DATE(YEAR($F$2),MONTH($F$2),$G$2))
```

I haven't used TODAY to get today's date because it's volatile and if you use it, it will keep prompting you to save the spreadsheet when you close it even if you haven't changed anything.

[image]